# Checking non-standard file extensions with Cppcheck

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

Is there a way to pass custom file extensions to [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/)? For example, `*.pc`.

Comment: Should this be tagged `c++` instead of `c`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: cppcheck can work with C code too.

Comment: @sharptooth: so it appears. Can you answer the question as well? ;-)

Comment: I think it is not possible (but i'm not sure), maybe you can write a simple script that copies files to correct extension and exec cppcheck and remove files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure. cppcheck will check any file that you give it.

check the file xyz.pc:

```
cppcheck xyz.pc
```

check all files with extension pc in folder srcfolder (this at least works in linux):

```
cppcheck srcfolder/*.pc
```

the --file-list flag may also be useful. you could generate the list of files that you want to check using an arbitrary script. and then run cppcheck on that file list.

```
cppcheck --file-list=files.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up writing a script to gather all the file types into a list, and pass that in.

Comment: @Daniel Marjamäki  Would it be possible to add a command line option to specify extensions to look at ?  For instance, I use .cxx, .hxx and .inl for my C++ projects.  I would rather not have to specify those files or create an alias for cppcheck that is cppcheck --file-list=<file-with-my-standard-extensions>.

Comment: not sure.. I am not _against_ it. It's just that we are pretty careful about adding command line arguments and this is not a common feature request. The .cxx is handled already. I would recommend that you dont add headers (.hxx) it is better for the analysis if you include those and check the source files. I do not know what .inl is, is that included files also?

Comment: is there any way to add this functionality to a powershell script so that it auto runs rather than typing it in a terminal?